# Numerical simulation of electromagnetism force from random wire

Tags: electromagnetism, simulations

I want to learn numerical simulation and as my first project I would like to simulate electromagnetic field derived from DC flowing in random shaped wire.

Are Maxwell equations enough to calculate 3D representation of current?
Or what other equations are needed?
Do you know any papers on this topic?

To throw more context - I want to write a program in java that could visualize flow.

Cheers.

Comment: Biot savart law.

Comment: @Jasper is it possible to derive this law from Maxwell Equations?

Comment: According to German Wikipedia: yes.